# invoke onclick event on a div attached by dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I added onclick using dojo to one of my divs

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("button1"), "onclick", function () {
alert('clicked');
}
```

I now need to call the exact same function dynamically in some other part of Javascript, I tried

```
dojo.byId("button1").onclick();.
```

It did not work. Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
dojo.query("#button1").onclick(function(e){ 
alert('clicked');
})

dojo.byId('button1').click();
```

Here's a [JSFiddle with it](http://jsfiddle.net/hEHcf/11/).